# Host .NET Core console application like Windows Service

Tags: .net, .net-core

My worker process is a .net core console app. How can I host it like windows service?

Because in current implementation I think if I pack it into something like **nssm** it will stuck due to Console.ReadKey(); but I still need to handle stopping event.

```
public class Program
{
    private Program()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var startup = new Startup();
        startup.ConfigureServices(services);

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var workerService = serviceProvider.GetService<WorkerService>();


        workerService.Run();

        Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages. Hit any key to quit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        workerService.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET core app or a standard .NET Core console app? If so, there are some ways to 'host' a .NET console app as a Windows Service (not as easy as the built int ASP.NET core methods) http://www.ben-morris.com/running-a-net-core-console-application-as-a-windows-service/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In .NET Core 2.1 you can use the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class to create and run service/daemon like applications.

You can configure and run your application in almost the same way as if it were an ASP.NET Core application. Despite the article titles, this isn't specific to ASP.NET Core, the Generic Host Builder is deployed through the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/) package that has no ASP.NET Core dependency.

The main method could look like this :

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseConsoleLifetime()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
            services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

The services that need to run as long as the application runs should implement [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=aspnetcore-2.1). This is described in [Background tasks with hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

The [UseConsoleLifetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#useconsolelifetime) call configures the host to check for `Ctrl+C` and terminate the application. When that happens, the host will call the [StopAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method of any configured service that implements the `IHostedService` interface.

When [RunAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#runasync) is called it will call the [StartAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.startasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method of any service that implements IHostedService.

You can also call [RunConsoleAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#runconsoleasync) to configure console lifetime and start the services without the extra call to `UseConsoleLifetime()`.

`RunAsync` and `RunConsoleAsync` will block until the host terminates. You can use `Start` or [StartAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#start-and-stopasync) to start the services and keep processing eg console input or external commands. When the time comes to terminate the application, for example in response to an `exit` input, you can call `StopAsync`.

For example :

```
host.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Type exit or Ctrl+C to exit");
while(Console.ReadLine() !="exit")
{
    //..
}

await host.StopAsync();
```

Of course, this could be used for something more substantial like listening from commands on a port

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a custom stop signal, use the *standard* of `CTRL-C` to break your process. There are some examples in [`Console.CancelKeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx) showing how that event can be reacted to, where you can place your `workerService.Stop()` statement, for example.

Tools like nssm can be configured to send the `CTRL-C` signal to initiate service shut-down, and it's somewhat expected that any wrapper system will offer similar functionality.